# How to bypass read timed out error while making callouts?

Tags: apex, integration, governorlimits

I have been trying making a request to Amazon Web Server, to send a document. In the request header, I am required to set a header named, Content-Length, which is currently being set to the BodyLength field of attachment. The issue being faced is the read timed out error, which was set to 120000 milliseconds in apex.

Is there any way to bypass this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Governor limits can't be bypassed, if they could be bypassed then it defeats the purpose of having them in the first place.

You have to change your architecture, the current one has limits on timeout and size of documents(6MB, 12MB heap limits)

You have to use a middleware, you can call middleware and provide the document id, it will download the document using the Rest API and then send it to AWS, once uploading to aws is complete, it can send an acknowledgment of it back to you,(You have to expose some custom Apex rest API)

You can even take it to the next level, and use platform events instead of the callout to 3rd party.

src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_remote_process_invocation_fire_forget.htm

Comment: +1 for `Governor limits can't be bypassed, if they could be bypassed then it defeats the purpose of having them in the first place.`